# ibm watson integrate with give wp

Tags: arrays, ibm-watson, watson-assistant, ibm-connections

Through the give api, create a function in ibm cloud functions in python that calls the form data:

```
import requests
import json

def main(args):
    # Definir los parámetros de la solicitud
    api_key = args.get('c7a1b1d5932a4ec9b7d6d9dfaa3cc486')
    api_token = args.get('7f26caf9f77a4fac61ba9a707deef841')
    api_url = 'https://juntospornaturaleza.profonanpe.org.pe/give-api/forms/'

    # Realizar la solicitud al API REST
    headers = {
        'Authorization': f'Token {api_key}:{api_token}',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
    response = requests.get(api_url, headers=headers)

    # Analizar la respuesta del API REST
    data = json.loads(response.content)

    # Procesar los datos según sea necesario
    forms = data['forms']
    form_titles = []
    for form in forms:
        form_titles.append(form['info']['title'])

    # Devolver la salida de la función
    return {'form_titles': form_titles}
```

results:

Activation ID:
312bf8e3e92249adabf8e3e92239ad77
Results:
{
"form_titles": [
"#RecuperoMiMar",
"#AnimalFans",
"Apadrina una taricaya, conserva Pacaya"
]
}
Logs:
[]

now I want that data to be read by my watson instance

Comment: Add more details on the actual problem. This looks ok.

Comment: you probably want to use https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/watson-assistant?topic=watson-assistant-build-custom-extension to call your cloud function